# The term 'EXEC' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssis, dtexec

I have an SSIS dtsx package that I want to run using PowerShell. Below is what I am running in powershell.

```bsh
EXEC xp_cmdshell '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "F:\SqlExport\New package.dtsx"'
```

Unfortunately I get the below error, and I dont know why

```
EXEC : The term 'EXEC' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ EXEC xp_cmdshell '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn ...
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (EXEC:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have enabled the `xp_cmdshell` in SQL Server using below command as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXEC xp_cmdshell` is a [T-SQL statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for **launching shell commands via `cmd.exe`**.

I presume the intent is to have PowerShell execute the command that starts with executable path `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe"`, *launched from your T-SQL script via `EXEC xp_cmdshell`*<sup>[1]</sup>.

Instead, **your error message implies that PowerShell executed the *entire line*, which predictably failed**: PowerShell has no `EXEC` command (and there is no external program by that name on your system).

That said, **PowerShell is neither needed here, nor would it enter the picture**, if your `EXEC xp_cmdshell` line had been executed by SQL Server (via a T-SQL script).

In fact, **your T-SQL command should work *as-is*** (invocation of an external program with arguments, via `cmd.exe`), if properly executed by SQL Server.

---

[1] *Update*: If the intent is simply to launch the command *from PowerShell*

```
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "F:\SqlExport\New package.dtsx"`
```

Note the need for `&`, the call operator, to tell PowerShell that the double-quoted string that follows is the name of an executable to invoke.